# algorithm query

Tags: algorithm, big-o

If we know the *lower* bound for the time complexity of a problem is `Ω(n^2)`, am I correct in thinking it is not possible to have an algorithm with worst-case time complexity `O(n log n)`?

Comment: Did you mean lower bound of n^2?

Comment: Can you give an example for a problem with an upper bound of O(n^2)?

Comment: Then the answer is no. It is as if you would ask "if I know that x is smaller than 8, am I correct to assume that x is larger than 6?"

Comment: Still possible, because `n^2` is *upper* bound. It wouldn't be, if `n^2` was *lower* bound.

Comment: apologies I have made a mistake in the question, what I meant to say was If a lower bound of omega (n^2) and NOT upper bound of O(n^2)

Comment: Yes, that's what the word *bound* means.

Answer (score 0):

If the lower bound for the time complexity of a problem is `Ω(n^2)`, then that means an algorithm solving this problem has to take **at least** `C*n^2` time.

On the other hand, you have an algorithm that takes **at most** `K*n*logn` time.

This algorithm cannot run any longer than `nlogn`. What you need is an algorithm that runs at least `n^2` time.

Therefore; it is impossible for this algorithm to solve this problem. You are correct.